# How to Configure Bean Pools for Session and Message-Driven Beans using the Management Console and the CLI tool for Jboss

Tags: jboss

I found solution for creating and editing the bean pool configuration for Jboss version EAP 6.0

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Create_a_Bean_Pool1.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Edit_a_Bean_Pool1.html

**Worker MDB:**

`@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(prop ertyName="destinationType" , propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"), @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination" , propertyValue="queue/replenish") @ActivationConfigProperty(prop ertyName=”minSessions” , propertyValue=”25”) @ActivationConfigProperty(prop ertyName=”maxSessions” , propertyValue=”50”) })`

I need same solution for both Jboss EAP 7.0 and Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final ? [ How To create or edit bean pools, “Create a Bean Pool” and , “Edit a Bean Pool” using the Management Console and the CLI tool for both Jboss EAP 7.0 and Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final ? slsb-strict-max-pool mdb-strict-max-pool ]

Comment: What is your particular problem in EAP 7.0? Do you miss certain controls / panels / ...?

Comment: Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final - How to configure same for this version?

Comment: Ivan : Jboss EAP 7.0 have same configuration process like EAP 6.1 what I mentioned because we are going to upgrade.

Comment: Beacause we are going to upgrade from Jboss AS 6.1.0  to EAP 7.0 . And also need to provide same configuration to currently running Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final.

Comment: Although the screenshot says 6.0, the url in documentation says 6.1. Have you tried following the documentation? What are the differences between the documentation and menus you see in your JBoss?

Comment: Sorry.. I don't have access I got from Jboss link, I assuming its supporting from EAP 6.0.

Comment: Please any one can responce for this..
How I need same solution for both Jboss EAP 7.0 and Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final

Comment: If you need help, please provide additional details. It's not clear without screenshots and stuff what is your problem. Also please read on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: How to Configure Bean Pools for Session and Message-Driven Beans using the Management Console and the CLI tool for Jboss EAP 7.0 and Jboss AS 6.1.0.Final

Comment: Hi Ivan,
 

How to Configure Bean Pools for Session and Message-Driven Beans using the configuration file for Jboss EAP 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but @pool is annotation based Jboss specific one

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.defaults.PoolDefaults;
@Stateless
@Pool (value=PoolDefaults.POOL_IMPLEMENTATION_STRICTMAX,maxSize=5,timeout=1000)
@Remote(StrictlyPooledSession.class)
public class StrictlyPooledSessionBean implements StrictlyPooledSession
{
...
}


XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aop xmlns="urn:jboss:aop-beans:1.0">

   <domain name="Strictly Pooled Stateless Bean" extends="Stateless Bean" inheritBindings="true">
      <annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool)">
          @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=5, timeout=10000)
      </annotation>
   </domain>

   <domain name="Strictly Pooled Message Driven Bean" extends="Message Driven Bean" inheritBindings="true">
      <annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool)">
          @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=5, timeout=10000)
      </annotation>
   </domain>
</aop>
```

Found in Link: http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/1.0.7/html/SessionBean_and_MDB_configuration.html

Please suggest Above explained annotation based is this right way to Implement and use strictMaxPool or NOT?

If it's not Right way then How I can configure the same "strictMaxPool" throught the xml file or configuration Files or annotation based ?